# CSV Encoding Issue on PHP upload

Tags: php, csv

I receive a csv file that looks fairly straightforward.

I run this on it and it tells me its ASCII.

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($fhandle , "auto");
```

However when i run my import code: It doesnt work correctly.

```
$sql= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '". $fhandle ."' INTO TABLE sys6_impBet FIELDS     TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  IGNORE 1 LINES

(       AccNo_1,

    MtgDate,

    Code,

    Venue,

    Location,

    Pool,

    EventNo,

    Gross_Sales,

    Refunds,

    Turnover,

    Dividends,

    Profit_Loss);" ;
```

It brings in the correct number of records but puts a NULL or 0 in every field / record. 
So it is reading the file as it sees the records but won't get the values.

Heres a small sample:

AccNo_1,MtgDate,Code,Venue,Location,Pool,EventNo,Gross_Sales,Refunds,Turnover,Dividends,Profit_Loss
66096159,12/07/2015,Gallops,Penola,SA,Treble,0,279.00,0.00,279.00,"1,955.70","1,676.70"
66096159,12/07/2015,Gallops,Warrnambool,VIC,Treble,0,"1,048.00",0.00,"1,048.00","2,672.80","1,624.80"
66096718,12/07/2015,Gallops,Kalgoorlie,WA,Win,2,783.00,0.00,783.00,"1,174.50",391.50
66096718,12/07/2015,Gallops,Penola,SA,Win,6,204.00,0.00,204.00,"1,143.00",939.00
66096718,12/07/2015,Gallops,Sha Tin,HK,Win,4,197.00,0.00,197.00,"2,064.00","1,867.00"

Is it an encoding problem.

IF I open the file in notepad and save as encoding UTF-8 and save it back down. Then the above code works and all is imported.

But I cant do that for every file every day??

Any ideas I can try?

I have tried this but no different:

```
$fhandle = mb_convert_encoding($fhandle, "UTF-8", "ASCII");
```

S

Answer (score 0):

first check the internal encoding used by php

echo mb_internal_encoding();

then set it to required one

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");